# PHP - adding new "key-value" to associative array

Tags: php

I'm trying almost everything to add a new key and its value to a result query.

```
    $consulta = "SELECT p.id_empleado,count(p.id_empleado) as pendientes,e.nombre,e.apellidos FROM partidas_empleados p ";
    $consulta.= "inner join empleados e on p.id_empleado=e.id_empleado ";
    $consulta.= "WHERE abierta=TRUE group by id_empleado";

    $sql = $con->prepare($consulta);
    $ok = $sql->execute();
    $query = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    for($i=0;$i<count($query);$i++){
        //echo "hola";
        $fila = $query[$i];
        $consulta = "SELECT id_partida FROM partidas_empleados where id_empleado=? ";
        $sql = $con->prepare($consulta);
        $ok = $sql->execute(array($fila['id_empleado']));
        $sub_query = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo $sub_query;
        //$fila[]= array("lista_partidas"=>$sub_query);
        $fila['lista_partidas']= $sub_query;
    }
```

`$sub_query` is just a list of asociative arrays

I'm trying to add `$sub_query` to `$query` with `lista_partidas` as a key.

Comment: What does `$fila` look like after you try adding the `$sub_query`? Does the key get added but no value? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: `$query[$i]['lista_partidas'] = $sub_query;`

Comment: Keep in mind, `$fila` is a _copy_ of `$query`. Adding to `$fila` will not change the `$query` variable.

Comment: @kunruh you are a life saver, i thought i was taking the reference.

Comment: @kunruh @jeroen I'm trying `$query[$i]['lista_partidas'] = $sub_query;` is not working :/

Comment: Sorry i had a typo. Is working fine.

Comment: @jeroen Post that as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kunruh and @jeroen said I was creating a copy of and modifying that copy.

```
    $consulta = "SELECT p.id_empleado,count(p.id_empleado) as pendientes,e.nombre,e.apellidos FROM partidas_empleados p ";
    $consulta.= "inner join empleados e on p.id_empleado=e.id_empleado ";
    $consulta.= "WHERE abierta=TRUE group by id_empleado";

    $sql = $con->prepare($consulta);
    $ok = $sql->execute();
    $query = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    for($i=0;$i<count($query);$i++){
        $consulta = "SELECT id_partida FROM partidas_empleados where id_empleado=? ";
        $sql = $con->prepare($consulta);
        $ok = $sql->execute(array($fila['id_empleado']));
        $sub_query = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query[$i]['lista_partidas']= $sub_query;
    }
```